# Website redirection problems

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I have been working on a website that is primarily PHP based. When a user visits the site stuff like http://robroscoe.ca/index.php, is redirected to `http://robroscoe.ca` and I am okay with this. What I am not okay with is, my webpages like `robroscoe.ca/cv.php` when you type in `robroscoe.ca/cv` redirecting back to `robroscoe.ca`. I am not sure how this happened and I am wondering if someone could explain to me what is going on.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I think the `.htaccess` file has something to do with this but I am not sure how to modify this as Wordpress seems to have created this for me without me knowing it. Any help or reading materials would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What's your permalink structure set to in Wordpress configuration? And does the page `cv` exist inside Wordpress?

Comment: The pages CV and other pages are external to the Wordpress site as they where created before Wordpress was added to the site which started out as only static pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you've created a PHP script that is *separate from WordPress* and are trying to access it through a 'pretty' URL which WordPress handles. WordPress does not know of a page called 'cv', and handles it like any other 404.

I would *strongly* recommend that you create the page within WP so it can manage its own 'pretty URL' structure.

If you're hellbent on shoehorning your own scripts in, then get cozy with hand-editing your .htaccess file for each one.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cv/?$ cv.php [L]   #new rule
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  #this is made redundant by the very next line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do I do if my static pages reside outside of my Wordpress install? I am not looking to do this for every page I am just looking to get the functionality I had before I added Wordpress back :)

Comment: @BadR0b1t if you're fine with having normal URLs like `/cv.php`, then you don't have to do anything the rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` basically says "if the file exists, don't redirect". If you moved everything to another folder with its own .htaccess file it *might* allow you to trim off the `.php` extension because of the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` rule, but how well that would work would need some testing.

Comment: is it possible to create a rule that would say if someone asked for example.com/about and there was a page about to automatically append the php to it? I am not so worried about the URL not containing the PHP but just ensuring that people get to the pages that they want to go to. The problem is right now if I ask for robroscoe.ca/cv it goes to the index instead of the PHP page for the CV.

Comment: @BadR0b1t Wordpress fully controls what content is shown for URLs that do not match the names of files and folders that *do* exist. To accomplish what you ask you'd need to find a Wordpress plugin to do this, or transfer the content *out of the external script* and into Wordpress. You cannot shoehorn what you are asking into the .htaccess file without breaking wordpress.